# Windows Phone - IsolatedStorage - get directory size

Tags: windows-phone-7, size, isolatedstorage

How can I get Directory size in IsolatedStorage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no API to get the total size of a specific directory in the isolated storage. Therefore, the only alternative you have is to browse the files and manually compute the total size.

Edit: Here is a sample implementation:

```
long total = 0;

using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    string folder = "folder/";

    foreach (var fileName in isolatedStorage.GetFileNames(folder))
    {
        using (var file = isolatedStorage.OpenFile(folder + fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            total += file.Length;
        }
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(total + " bytes");
```

Comment: Can you give me any example how to do that?